# Varnish for MongoDB, is it necessary?

Tags: mongodb, performance, rest, caching, varnish

I read that:
MongoDB keeps most recently used data in RAM. If you have created indexes for your queries and your working data set fits in RAM, MongoDB serves all queries from memory.

Is it necessary to build a Varnish cache for a REST API that talks to mongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

In a direct communication with a MongoDB or even other databases, Varnish cache is not necessary because almost all up to date databases have caching techniques.

But in front of a web server I strongly recommend Varnish. It can considerably increase the number of requests your web server can respond because even though you database already has the answer for a repeated query, you web server will still need to:

1. Parse the request;
2. Forward a query to the db;
3. Prepare the response;
4. Respond to the requester.

With Varnish in front of your web server, it will need to do none of those steps. In that scenario Varnish would decrease not only the number of requests your web server needs to respond but also the queries to the database.

Also it is worth to mention that if your database is not on the same server of your API, even your it responding pretty fast there is also a network delay that must come into play if your looking for hardcore performance.